# Call Winzip32.exe with parameter with c#

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, winzip

I want zip folder through my console application that's why I used something like

```
public void DoWinzip(string zipName, string password, string folderName)
        {
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.FileName = "C:\\Program Files\\WinZip\\winzip32.exe";
            startInfo.Arguments = string.Format("-min -eZ {0} {1}", zipName, folderName);

            try
            {
                // Start the process with the info we specified.
                // Call WaitForExit and then the using statement will close.
                using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo))
                {
                    exeProcess.WaitForExit();
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                // Log error.
            }

        }
```

But this will give me error like winzip parameters validation error. Where I do mistake?

```
Update
```

I spell wrong on -eZ actually it may -ex etc...  But another problem is that winzip open up own windows. I write for it -min however it opened.

Comment: Why not use SharpZipLib (http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/)?  Then you have full control of the zipping process.

Comment: I do that it is fine but it gives zip file with more MB Size than winzip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid to open up windows by using ProcessStartInfo.WindowStyle property

Try this:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = "C:\\Program Files\\WinZip\\winzip32.exe";
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are passing paths with whitespaces (in `zipName` and `folderName` arguments) without enclosing them in double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.rondebruin.nl/parameters.htm -> looking at that I would think the code is:

startInfo.Arguments = string.Format("-e {0} {1}", zipName, folderName);

Comment: Also, maybe try debugging startInfo.Arguments after setting them, to make sure you actually pass on the desired input.

Answer (score 0):

What is the option `-eZ`?  I think that is your issue

I thought that that following are the only options to determine the compression method.

`-ex` = eXtra

`-en` = Normal

`-ef` = Fast

`-es` = Super fast

`-e0` = no compression